# SwiftUI Image AspectFit ratio not working properly with screen width

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, scrollview, padding

I am trying to keep image width equal to screen with aspectfit ratio.I am adding Text on remaining screen height.It is working well untill text height touch the bottom view line.There is unexpected auto left and right space is added around image.It is more visible if i use the same view in tab bar.

I also use **GeometryReader** and define some area to image and text but unfortunetely it's also not working.

I try it with other combination like Image and ScrollView , Image and List but still no luck.

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Image("tickimg")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(minWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .border(Color.yellow)
                        Text("HelloWorld\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn\n\n\n").background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Extra space on left and right side]

Here is complete project link
https://github.com/umair-Ahm/ImagePadding

Is it possible to acheive it without spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                }
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .border(.yellow)

                Text("HelloWorld\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nn\n\n\n").background(Color.red)
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep the left/right border with a 0 value.Is this possible?

Comment: Do you only want a border on the top and on the bottom? You can do .overlay(Rectangle().frame(width: nil, height: 1, alignment: .top).foregroundColor(Color.yellow), alignment: .top) and  .bottom for the bottom

Comment: Basically, I don't want an image side gap in any case. Like this 
https://ibb.co/Ph3Wzv4 
You can see that if we reduce the Text area, there is no side gap around the Image. I want similar behavior with full-text height.

Comment: I understand. I misunderstood your question, I thought you meant the small spacing which was the border. The horizontal spacing between the image and the width of your view is because the height of the image isn't the same frame as the width. I made the height now the same as the width (1x1). The reason reducing the text "worked" was that you set a minWidth instead of a static one. Check the updated answer